# How to assign to a TextFile variable?

Tags: delphi

The following code tries to assign one TextFile variable to another, but does not compile:

`[Error] Operator not applicable to this operand type`

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;
var t1, t2: TextFile;
begin
  t1 := t2; // <-- [Error] Operator not applicable to this operand type
end.
```

If it is possible to assign to a TextFile variable, one could be able to switch between `System.Output`, `Sytem.ErrOutput` and/or other `TextFile` instances easily. But, is the assignment possible ?

Comment: Don't use legacy I/O which does not support Unicode

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can one `Write` to `System.Output` or `System.ErrOutput` without using legacy I/O ?

Comment: Of course. It's perfectly possible to outpu to the standard handles without legacy I/O. How do you suppose the legacy I/O libs do so?

Comment: Just an explanation as to why this is not allowed.  A TextFile value contains state information.  Specifically it has a buffer.  See tTextRec.   When you write to a TextFile you are first writing to the buffer.  What would happen if you wrote something to T1, and then wrote something else to T2?  Now you've got two separate buffers with different text.  Using pointers is the way to go to solve the problem you've prevented.  Or, as has been said, don't use TextFile at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment to a `TextFile` variable doesn't seem to be supported but you can declare and use a pointer type:

```
type
  PTextFile = ^TextFile;

var
  F: PTextFile;
begin
  F := @Output;
  Writeln(F^, 'Hello');

  F := @ErrOutput;
  Writeln(F^, 'Hello');

  AssignFile(F^, 'test.txt');
  Rewrite(F^);
  Writeln(F^, 'Hello');
  CloseFile(F^);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Could you help to comment whether it is possible to do without pointer ? (If it is possible, the code will be compatible with Delphi for .Net, which is a plus).

Comment: As I said, it doesn't seem to be supported. I don't know if `TextFile` is even supported in .NET but I doubt it - there seems to be some compiler magic involved in the ancient `TextFile` and related functions.

Comment: If you don't like pointers, use some other form of indirection. A case statement on an enum would do. Pointers seems like the way though.